# Spring security programmatic in-memory UserDetailsService: username and roles, NO password

Tags: java, spring, security, authorization, programmatic-config

UPDATE:  I was not able to solve the problem presented here, but the simplest and most effective solution to my problem was to NOT use the in-memory userDetailsService.  Details of my resulting solution are in a follow-up post.

---

SUMMARY

With the old SpringSecurity.xml I never needed to provide the password to support additional ROLEs via the in-memory userDetailsService.  It was very convenient, especially during the development phase.

With the programmatic approach it is easy to provide username+password+roles, but it is not clear how to provide **only** username+roles.  I would like to learn how.

EXAMPLES

In the examples below "user" does authentication and authorization in Active Directory through adAuthProvider.  The programmatic examples are the full content of the SecurityConfig configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method.

security.xml:
(this worked for years, what I want to replicate)

```
  <sec:user-service id="xmlUserDetailsService">
    <sec:user name="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
  </sec:user-service>
```

Failed programmatic attempt:
(direct translation of the above, notice that "user" does not setup the password... like in the XML above).
Throws during server start: (org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor)

```
  auth.authenticationProvider(adAuthProvider);
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
  .withUser("user").roles("USER")
```

Successful, adding the password for "user":
(exception goes away)

```
  auth.authenticationProvider(adAuthProvider);
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
  .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
  .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("user")).roles("USER")
```

QUESTION:

1. I assume that XML and programmatic configurations are supposed to be equivalent.  Thus I assume there is a way to avoid supplying the password to the in-memory userDetails.  Is this correct?
2. Assuming the above is true, how do I do it?  Could you please provide an example for the whole method?

I realize this is probably a trivial question.  I googled and reviewed easily 100 examples, but they all include the password.  Not a single one showed how to use in-memory just for authorization - relying on the Active Directory authentication provider to validate the password.

Comment: They aren't equivalent the XML one also has a password, although that is a random one. They are also different in that the XML one does a setup for an `InMemoryUserDetailsService` which you then probably use in your AD configuration to map the roles. In your Java version it sets up a full `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, while you probably still need the `UserDetailsService` to retrieve the users roles. But to fix this, just assign a random password, just like the XML one.

Comment: Ty Deinum.  You are right that in XML the info is provided through the userDetailsService, although the password field was optional, not mandatory like it is in the programmatic authentication provider.  I have not seen a programmatic example for how to setup a UserDetailsService separate from the AuthenticationProvider, but I can probably find one.  Do you know if in the programmatic UserDetailsService the password is optional as in XML?  Or would it be a wasted effort?  Keep in mind that my intention is for authentication and most of the authorization to be done in AD, a few ROLEs in svc.

Comment: A password isn't optional for the user, but in XML when not provided a random one is generated. So just assign a random (or dymmy) password when creating the `InMemoryUserDetailsService`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following helps the next googler with my problem.

First, my thanks to Deinum, he got me thinking in the right direction.

Just adding using a dummy password in the code of the original post did not work, but this worked even better for my needs:

- **I was already using a custom AuthenticationProvider**.  It was easy to place and read the extra roles for users from a value in the property file with the JSON syntax:  **springsecurity.extraRoles=[{"username":"usernameValue", "roles":["ROLE_XTRA1", "ROLE_XTRA2"]}]**.
- The extra roles rarely change, so they get read into a static Map, and are added to the user roles retrieved from AD as part of the authenticate() process.
- And since I already had the property **deploy.environment=DEV**, I used it to disable the mechanism in PROD.  A safety net against deployment mistakes.

---

This description should be sufficient, but let me know if anyone needs a more detailed explanation of any of the steps.